# SAPUI5 Splitter Layout on VIew but not using splitApp

Tags: android, layout, sapui5, splitter

I'm using the sap.m.App in my SAPUI5 application and I'd like to put on page a splitter layout.

I didn't create as sap.m.splitApp because I have some view that I don't want as splitter layout.

How can I put a splitter layout on specifics views?

My test view:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" controllerName="controller.MyList"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page showNavButton="{device>/isPhone}" navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress"
    title="{i18n>MY_LIST_TITLE}">
    <l:Splitter height="500px">
    <Toolbar>
        <SearchField id = "search" search ="handleSearch" width="100%" />
    </Toolbar>
    <List
        id="myList"
        mode="{device>/listMode}"
        select="handleListSelect"
        items="{/LIST}" >
        <ObjectListItem
            type="{device>/listItemType}"
            press="handleListItemPress"
            title="{ID}">
            <attributes>
                <ObjectAttribute text="{DESCRIPTION}" />
            </attributes>
            <firstStatus>
                <ObjectStatus text="STATUS" />
            </firstStatus>
        </ObjectListItem>
    </List> 
    </l:Splitter>
 </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

The result is:

[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Not sure what your issue is?... the splitter is perfectly shown as expected

Comment: Qualiture, thanks for reply! Actually, I'd like that the list stay under the search field.

Comment: Well, what stops you from encapsulating both controls in a VBox or VerticalLayout so they both show up underneath each other ;-)

Comment: Qualiture, when I put the items underneath each other using VBox, the splitter layout is not showed. - I'm try to do following this [tutorial](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/8022ac87-1f60-3110-5383-fa68a91d7f8b?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&59017145622993) but with a login page, after a page with tile container and than the split layout.

Comment: Yes, but you should of course put some other content in the right pane of course; adding just a `VBox` with the toolbar and list in the left pane, and nothing in the right pane, will of course not show a right pane then

Comment: Qualiture, I tried to do that, but didn't work as I hoped. So, I solved my problem creating a splitApp. But now, I don't know how to go back to my previous app. More information in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817034/sapui5-navigation-between-apps-definitions). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Attached screen app you can develop using split app Technics only.
as you mention "some view that I don't want as slitter layout" - for those I can suggest u to use fullScreenPageRoutes

```
       fullScreenPageRoutes : {

        "summaryPage": {
            pattern : "summary",
            view : "summaryView"
         },
        }
```

Comment: Kitty, thanks for reply! I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/8022ac87-1f60-3110-5383-fa68a91d7f8b?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&59017145622993), but in my case, I have to create a Login page and a Start Center page with tile options! So, I'm not using the router to navigate through pages.